# Honorific suffix 御 as in 甥御 and 姪御?

Tags: words, honorifics

Just learned that the honorific equivalents of nephew and niece in Japanese are:
**甥御** and **姪御**, which raise the question:

**How come 御 functions as a suffix instead of a prefix which is the case we usually see? Are there other common examples of this phenomenon?**

Incidentally, according to goo辞書, they are generally written in kana instead of kanji. I used their kanji for the sake of clarity.

*Been slacking off with my Japanese lately, but よろしくお願いいたします！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

御 *-go* is a suffix, distinct from the prefix *go-*.  The suffix is used to show "light respect" towards human beings only, mostly after family terms (so not for general nouns like *go-Iken*, etc.).  The *Kokugo Daijiten* dictionary attributes it to an abbreviation of 御前 *Goze*.

*Goze*, *Gozen* was originally a word for nobility, then a respectful term for adult women, then a respectful term *of address* for women (a treatment pronoun).  By the 13th century we see *-goze* used as a polite suffix; in the *Heike Monotagari* (*Tale of the House of Taira*) we have characters addressing others like やや副将御ぜ *Yaya, Fukushō-goze…* “Well now, Lord Vice-captain…”

In the same work we have the first known appearance of *-go* as 母御 (modern *Haha-go*).  By the time the Jesuits came and described the language, around 1604, [they found it in use](https://books.google.de/books?id=GB8YAAAAYAAJ&dq=V%C3%B4gigo&hl=de&pg=PA320#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the whole family: *Faua-go* (*Fawa-go*, modern *Haha-go*), *Tete-go* (father), *Vôgi-go* (ヲウチゴ *Wōdji-go*, modern *Ojī-go*, grandfather (not *Ōji*, prince)), *Ani-go* older brother, *Vototo-go* (*Wototo* > *Otōto*), *Vba-go* (*Uba-go* > *Uba*), *Vôba-go* (*Wōba* ?> *Obā*), "&c.".

The Jesuits explain of *-goien* (*gojen* = ごぜん; ぜ was like じぇ at the time) and its reduced form *-go* that:

> The first particle of these two [=ごぜん] is proper solely for women, & honour them in the manner of *Sama*, out of respect for the noble people to whom such women belong. […] *-Go* [, by contrast,] is proper for men & women.

Notice that this is already different from the use of *-goze* to address the captain in the *Heike*.  Apparently the longer form became sufficiently associated with women that the shorter *-go* replaced it as a gender-neutral suffix.

Sources:

- *Kokugo Daijiten*.
- *Arte da lingoa de Iapam* (my translation).